# Why is observableArray not observable in Knockout JS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I am new to programming (especially in JS and even more with KO) and I'm trying to come up with an interactive quiz destined to be used in class by high-school students. Thanks to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/365120/KnockoutJS-vs-Silverlight) (which provided the how-to and the code, which I used as a base, trying to readapt it to my needs) and some good people's help here, I have now come up with something that looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/sNJm3/2/

All is well because this is functional. But... :p I would now like to add an observableArray where I would push() all the selectedAnswer each time the user clicks one so that I could, at the end, compare selectedAnswers().length to questions().length and, if they are the same, I'd make a  (not included in the code yet) visible.

I declared my array in the QuizViewModel constructor like so (as it concerns the whole quiz, so I think that's where it should go):

```
var selectedAnswers = ko.observableArray();
```

And then I need, each time, to push the selectedAnswer property from the Question constructor into it. And that's where the rub is... Here's the part of my script:

```
//Construction
$.each(quizName.controls, function(index, question) {
    quiz.questions.push(new Question(index + 1, question));
    quiz.selectedAnswers().push(question.selectedAnswer);
});
```

This does populate an array called selectedAnswers() but it is only populated with Undefineds, which 1) do not vary even when I click an answer (undefined is not replaced with clicked selectedAnswer...) and selectedAnswers().length is already equal to the total number of questions, which means the comparison I wanted to make will not work...

There must be some fundamental KO logic I'm not getting here (or is it JS logic, which definitely seems to be eluding me!) Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is wrong in your fiddle?

Comment: @AshReva Everything's right, but if you take a peek at the console, then you'll see that selectedAnswers() has 6 undefineds instead of updating as I click along...
And I need it to be empty at the beginning and to add questions as I click so I have six ONLY AT THE END...

Comment: Thats because you are having this $.each when page is loading.

Comment: But I do need the $.each for something else... So where should I put my code to push the selectedAnswer of each question in my observable array?

Comment: cant you put that code on some button click , so its loaded only when required?

Comment: Or are you suggesting I get rid of the $.each altogether? In that case, how do I manage to populate my questions array?

Comment: i commented your code quiz.selectedAnswers().push(question.selectedAnswer);. take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sNJm3/10/  i dont think you needed to push at page load

Comment: Help! I don't understand? I thought $.each in my case was building all of the questions one after the other and therefore was necessary from the beginning (no questions ==> no quiz).

If I am mistaken, could you kindly explain that to me with code examples so I can try and understand exactly what it is doing, or what you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed for your "selected answers" list.

```
function Question(config) {
    this.text = text;
    this.questionText = config.questionText;
    this.answers = config.answers;
    this.selectedAnswer = ko.observable();
}

function QuizViewModel(quizName) {
    this.questions = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(quizName.controls, function (control) {
            return new Question(control);
        })
    );
    this.selectedAnswers = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(this.questions(), function (q) {
            return q.selectedAnswer();
        }
    });
}
```

There is no need to maintain a separate stack (i.e. observable array) of answers when the answer already is a property of the question itself.

Comment: cant we just uncomment code quiz.selectedAnswers().push(question.selectedAnswer); when page is loading. Why he needs to push selectedAnswers while page loading?

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: i meant why we need this code quiz.selectedAnswers().push(question.selectedAnswer);   in function quizmodel

Comment: Maybe you should ask the OP, not me? My answer does not have this line of code.

Comment: Hey @Tomalak, would it be possible for you to explain what ko.utils.arrayMap() is? I've never encountered THAT before, not even in the documentation (but I haven't read the whole thing, I'll admit!)

Comment: `ko.utils.arrayMap()` is an undocumented but supported utility function (there are a few others you can use, check out the `ko.utils` object). I use it mainly to work with knockout without creating dependencies to other libraries over such a simple thing as an array for-each.

Comment: Which means, if I understand you correctly, that I can get rid of jQuery in the scripts?

Comment: @ReinaDelSur *If* you only use it for the sake of `$.each()` (which I doubt), then yes. :) I try avoid jQuery in my viewmodels, because it is rarely necessary. View models ought to know nothing about the view that displays them. They only have logic, no DOM interaction. It's cleaner to keep the two separate, especially if it's as easy as here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZW4R/8/
After replacing my code with yours, I'm still getting an undefined error in the Question() constructor... Everything seems to be in order, though, so I don't understand why...